# Find the general solution of the next differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Im trying to solve this problem but have no idea how start

$$y''-\frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}y'+\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}y=(x^2+1)^2$$

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I think its equivalent to $(D + y)^2g = g^3$ if $g = g(x) = x^2 + 1$. Actually if you multiply by x^2 + 1 I think there is a Cauchy method that would probably work.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$y''-\dfrac{2x}{x^{2}+1} y'+\dfrac{2}{x^{2}+1}y=0$$
Note that $y=x$ is a solution. So try to  [reduce the order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order) with $y=vx$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y''-\dfrac{2x}{x^{2}+1} y'+\dfrac{2}{x^{2}+1}y=0$$

As @Satyendra answered, $y=x$ is a solution. There is another I found almost by accident which is $y=(x-i)^2$.

In both cases, you can reduce the order but the particular solution given by @Satyendra is from far away the simplest.

I suppose that tha particular solution is just a polynomial with only even powers (find why).

Comment: That gives $x^2+1$ if you split in real and imaginary part, which also must be solutions due the DE to being real and linear.